# React Page larger than screen size

Tags: css, node.js, reactjs, grommet

I am developing a react application which is longer than the available screen size on mobile, thus not allowing a proper scroll to the bottom (there is always content below the end of the screen on mobile). This means that a user has to do another scroll swipe, as this content outside will not scroll up by scrolling through the default list of components in the React application, but seemingly the viewport is too long and therefore overflows outside of the component.
[The scrollbar is apparent, which indicates that the content is longer than the available page size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UC4HZ.png)

I tried setting the overflow accordingly and also tried removing most properties and components, but the issue still persists.